# angularjs route - jump to specific page section on route link

Tags: html, angularjs, url-routing, angular-routing

I am trying to make some kind of a mix between an Angular anchor and routing...

I do have it working in the home page, since the anchor sections are there, however, if I am in another page, it does not.

Can anyone point me in the right direction on how to do it correctly, please?

Here´s what I have so far

```
freddoApp.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider

    // route for the home page
    .when('/', {
        templateUrl : 'pages/home/home.html',
        controller  : 'mainController'
    })

    // route for the productos page
    .when('/productos', {
        templateUrl : 'pages/home/home.html',
        controller  : 'mainController'
    })

    // route for the unico page
    .when('/unico', {
        templateUrl : 'pages/home/home.html',
        controller  : 'mainController'
    })

    // route for the sabores page
    .when('/sabores', {
        templateUrl : 'pages/home/home.html',
        controller  : 'mainController'
    })

    // route for the locales page
    .when('/locales', {
        templateUrl : 'pages/locales/locales.html',
        controller  : 'storeController'
    })

    // route for the servicios page
    .when('/servicios', {
        templateUrl : 'pages/servicios/servicios.html',
        controller  : 'servicesController'
    })

    // route for the about page
    .when('/about', {
        templateUrl : 'pages/about/about.html',
        controller  : 'aboutController'
    })

    // route for the contact page
    .when('/contact', {
        templateUrl : 'pages/contact/contact.html',
        controller  : 'contactController'
    });

    // use the HTML5 History API
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
});
```

/............................./

```
    freddoApp.controller('mainController', function($scope, $location, $anchorScroll) {

    $scope.scrollTo = function(id) {
        $location.hash(id);
        $anchorScroll();
    };
```

/............................./

(HTML)

```
<div id="freedo-nav-bar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a ng-click="scrollTo('productos')">Productos</a></li>
                    <li><a ng-click="scrollTo('unico')"> Freddo Único</a></li>
                    <li><a ng-click="scrollTo('sabores')"> Sabores</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#locales"> Locales</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#servicios"> Servicios</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#about"> Nosotros</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#contact"> Contacto</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

If i understand you right, i think you could solve this with resolve.

First add a resolve function to your routing:

```
.when('productos/', {
    templateUrl : 'pages/home/home.html',
    controller  : 'mainController',
    resolve: {
        anchorname: function() { {
            // anchor name
            return 'productos'
        }
    }
})
```

In your controller pass the resolve object and add some function for the scrolling

```
freddoApp.controller('mainController', function($scope, $location, $anchorScroll, anchorname) {

    if(anchorname){
        $location.hash(anchorname);
        $anchorScroll();
    }

})
```

This should immediately scroll to the anchor after you selecting the route.

EDIT: Its working, see here: https://jsfiddle.net/326f44xu/

Answer (score 4):

Best approach for you is using routing url params like `/home/:section`. If you do it in that way, you are able to access from any other page. <kbd>[PLUNKER](https://plnkr.co/edit/hseysbh5yjWMGaoQvKW1?p=preview)</kbd>

**ROUTE CONFIG**

```
app.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
  $routeProvider
  .when('/home/:section?', {
    templateUrl: 'home.html',
    controller: 'mainController'
  }) //You don't need to repeat your .when() multiple times

  $routeProvider.otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/home'
  });
});
```

**HOME CTRL** (mainController)

```
app.controller('mainController', function($routeParams, $location, $anchorScroll) {
  //wrap this on $onInit or activate() function if you want
  $location.hash($routeParams.section);
  $anchorScroll();
});
```

**HOME.HTML**

```
<div><!-- HOME --></div>
<div id="productos"><!-- Productos--></div>
<div id="unico"><!-- unico--></div>
<div id="sabores"><!-- sabores--></div>
```

**INDEX.HTML**

```
<body>
  <div>
    <a ng-href="#/home">Home</a>
    <a ng-href="#/home/productos">productos</a>
    <a ng-href="#/home/unico">Unicos</a>
    <a ng-href="#/home/sabores">Sabores</a>
  </div>

  <div ng-view></div>
</body>
```

---

** *You can use empty route with optional params like `/:section?`, but I added `/home` to make it clear. The `?` at the end of url param is to make it optional.*