# How can i route in to a specifig ng-include template

Tags: javascript, angularjs, url-routing

Currently i route in to a another controller like so when a link is being clicked

[image: creditchecklink]

creditcheck HTML:

```html
<h3 class="modal-title" focus-me="true">Credit check regarding
 <a ng-click="routeToSubOrg()">{{creditCheck.subOrganization.name}}</a>
</h3>
```

creditcheck JS:

```js
$scope.routeToSubOrg = function(){ const pathToSubOrg = "/recruitment/organization/"+$scope.creditCheck.subOrganization.organizationId;
            if($location.$$path !== pathToSubOrg)
            {
                $uibModalInstance.dismiss('close');
                $location.path(pathToSubOrg);
            }         
        }
```

I route to a specific html route which works, however i need to route to a specific uib-tab "Billing information" in here

[image: pill menu]

organizations HTML:

```html
   <uib-tabset type="pills header-menu">
        <uib-tab heading="General info" index="0">
            <div ng-include="'templates/organizations/organizations.generalinfo.html'" ng-controller="OrganizationsGeneralinfoController"> </div>
        </uib-tab>

        <uib-tab heading="Billing Information" ng-if="organization.id > 0" index="4">
            <div ng-include="'templates/suborganizations/organizations.suborganizations.html'" ng-controller="SubOrganizationsController"></div>
        </uib-tab>        
    </uib-tabset>
```

I cannot find a way to route to the billinginformation ng-include template automatically from a another page...

Comment: As per what I understood this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45489579/angularjs-route-jump-to-specific-page-section-on-route-link can help you

Comment: the thing is. The url on the page needs to stay the same "/recruitment/organizations/275". so that is unfortunately not my solution